# How to capture self consuming variable in a struct?

Tags: struct, rust

I have a Reader instance with a method that [consumes the Reader and returns a Writer](https://github.com/estebank/galvanize/blob/0abafb62fec98f257ebd27124b66131ec5d6216f/src/reader.rs#L320) and the Writer can similarly get back to a Reader again. It's trivial to use immutably, but I can't figure out how to hide the immutability from callers and just do the reader-writer-reader dance behind the scenes with a mutable Self.

Essentially I'd like something like:

```
struct Container<'a> {
    reader: Reader<'a, File>
}

fn update(&mut self) {
    let writer = self.reader.as_writer();
    writer.write_something();
    self.reader = writer.as_reader();
}
```

which just gives `cannot move out of borrowed content` error. Tried to add a Box, Cell, or RefCell around the Reader which just lead to other errors.

Can the `reader` be hidden behind a mutable interface or does it force the whole struct hierarchy to be mutable as well? (i.e. similar to IO in Haskell)

---

Self contained sample with the types matching the real thing (I think)

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NoCopy(u32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Flipper<'a, T: 'a> {
    data: &'a mut T,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Flopper<'a, T: 'a> {
    data: &'a mut T,
}
impl<'a, T> Flipper<'a, T> {
    fn flip(self) -> Flopper<'a, T> {
        Flopper{data: self.data}
    }
}
impl<'a, T> Flopper<'a, T> {
    fn flop(self) -> Flipper<'a, T> {
        Flipper{data: self.data}
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Container<'a, T: 'a> {
    flipper: Flipper<'a, T>,
}
impl<'a, T> Container<'a, T> {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        self.flipper = self.flipper.flip().flop();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Flipper{data: &mut NoCopy(42)};
    let f = f.flip().flop();
    println!("f={:?}", f);

    let mut c = Container{flipper: f};
    c.run();
    println!("c={:?}", c);
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:29:24
   |
29 |         self.flipper = self.flipper.flip().flop();
   |                        ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpler solution is to use an `Option` to wrap the `Reader`.

An `Option` has a `take` method which returns the content (and puts `None` in the `Option`), then you can place the `Reader` back by assigning.

```
struct Container<'a> {
    reader: Option<Reader<'a, File>>
}

fn update(&mut self) {
    let writer = self.reader.take().unwrap().as_writer();
                             ^~~~~~~
    writer.write_something();
    self.reader = Some(writer.as_reader());
                  ^~~~~                  ^
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing an `.unwrap()` after the take, but with that it works. /me slaps forehead

Comment: Is there a way to make it a compile error if the function tries to exit without restoring a `Some` back to the reader?

Comment: @TommiKomulainen: Not that I know of, no. There used to be proposals for giving Rust the ability to "punch holes" in `struct`/`enum` and then restore them... but this is tricky to ensure in the presence of `panic!` and unwinding.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Matthieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39881558/508716) I figured it's straightforward to add a (trivial) wrapper around the `Option` to enforce compile time checks that only allow "borrowing" the `Reader` instance while requiring another one is returned afterwards.

```
struct State<T>(Option<T>);

impl<T> State<T> {
    pub fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        State(Some(val))
    }
    pub fn modify<F>(&mut self, fun: F)
        where F: FnOnce(T) -> T
    {
        self.0 = Some(fun(self.0.take().unwrap()));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
fn modify(&mut self) {
    self.state.modify(|reader| {
        let writer = reader.as_writer();
        writer.write_something();
        writer.as_reader()
    }
}
```

Should be good enough to avoid accidental misuses. No idea about `panic!` unwindings though.

Probably not following Rust naming conventions, `state` and `modify` come from Haskell's `State`.

Comment: Well, if it panics before returning from the closure there will be a `None` in it.